# Textjoin: Using a unique ID, how do I concat multiple values?

Tags: excel-formula, textjoin

I'm having trouble getting this to work. Basically, I have the following set of data:

[image]

In the TextJoin Formula column, I want it to do a look up against the adjacent ID, scan the income code column and concat the income codes pertaining to that unique ID, separated by a ','.

[image]

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$6=$A2,$B$2:$B$6,""))
```

Depending on one's version this may require Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

If one has the Dynamic Array Formula FILTER:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER(B:B,A:A=A2))
```

Comment: I can confirm the first formula worked after doing Ctrl-Shift-Enter! Thanks so much Scott.

Comment: If the income code repeats against the unique ID, is there a way to limit the value to populating just once? E.g. if ABCD has Income code 5 appearing in two different rows, instead of it showing as 5,5 (how it populates currently) it just reflects as 5.

Comment: That is a different question. And it has been asked and answered before  do a quick search of stack overflow.